# Show Mapbox data in popup on hover

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am trying to show just city name and state in popup

This is what I currently have
https://jsfiddle.net/haberman/aj760ok1/1/

It will show all properties but I can't isolate just the city and state for some reason.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZnJzdHlsc2tpZXIiLCJhIjoiY2swd2p5OXZhMGdidDNlcGZzYXI2N3RrdSJ9.MY-V2IlbfRAWSEAIdXmhlA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/frstylskier/cknz0hf0u4ega17pe3vpd6e9l'
});

map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);

    // Limit the number of properties we're displaying for
    // legibility and performance
    var displayProperties = [
        'properties',
    ];

    var displayFeatures = features.map(function (feat) {
        var displayFeat = {};
        displayProperties.forEach(function (prop) {
            displayFeat[prop] = feat[prop];
        });
        return displayFeat;
    });

    document.getElementById('features').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        displayFeatures,
        null,
        2
    );
    
    
});
```

Comment: `displayFeatures[0].properties.name` and `state_abbrev`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to follow the properties path of the Object.

Instead of

```
    document.getElementById('features').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(
        displayFeatures,
        null,
        2
    );
```

use

```
    let feat = document.getElementById('features');
    feat.innerHTML = '<div class="city"></div><div class="state"></div>';
    // get the first item in the list, that has name and state_abbrev set
    let searchResult = displayFeatures.find(v => { // pin
        return typeof v.properties == "object" &&
          v.properties && // avoid null errors
          v.properties["Deals: Client City"] &&
          v.properties["Deals: Client State"]
      }) || displayFeatures.find(v => { // default
        return typeof v.properties == "object" &&
          v.properties && // avoid null errors
          v.properties.name &&
          v.properties.state_abbrev
      });
    // just map the pin names to the default names
    if (searchResult && searchResult.properties["Deals: Client City"]) {
      searchResult.properties.name = searchResult.properties["Deals: Client City"];
      searchResult.properties.state_abbrev = searchResult.properties["Deals: Client State"];
    }
    // add the values to the divs inside the node
    feat.querySelector(".city").innerText = searchResult ? searchResult.properties.name : "n/a";
    feat.querySelector(".state").innerText = searchResult ? searchResult.properties.state_abbrev : "n/a";
```

Comment: Awesome that works great, I tried to recreate what you said with a custom property were passing Deals: Client Name. 

I tried v.properties['Deals: Client City']
but it passes errors how would I target a custom property?

Comment: I just realized the issue with this, it shows me the city / state on the map not the pin

Comment: GOT IT just need to make it a pop up now